# Naming of an algorithmic antipattern

Tags: naming, complexity-theory, anti-patterns

I'm having problems to recall the name of doing something with quadratic complexity when it can be solved linearly.

For example, using a `get-by-index` function to iterate over a linked list instead of just using a `next-element` is the typical case of this antipattern.

I think it was the "something painter", as a metaphor of a guy that is painting a road, but doesn't carry with him the paint bucket and has to come back to the starting point every time he needs to refill the brush.

Cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You're probably thinking of [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm).**

There's a classic joke on the topic that Joel Spolsky included in his [*Back to Basics*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) article some years ago:

> Shlemiel gets a job as a street
>   painter, painting the dotted lines
>   down the middle of the road. On the
>   first day he takes a can of paint out
>   to the road and finishes 300 yards of
>   the road. "That's pretty good!" says
>   his boss, "you're a fast worker!" and
>   pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel only gets 150
>   yards done. "Well, that's not nearly
>   as good as yesterday, but you're still
>   a fast worker. 150 yards is
>   respectable," and pays him a kopeck.
>
> The next day Shlemiel paints 30 yards
>   of the road. "Only 30!" shouts his
>   boss. "That's unacceptable! On the
>   first day you did ten times that much
>   work! What's going on?"
>
> "I can't help it," says Shlemiel.
>   "Every day I get farther and farther
>   away from the paint can!"

P.S. *Don't confuse this with the [Painter's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm), which is an actual method for composing images.*