# Given an array, what's an efficient way to create an array of arrays where each of these subarrays has indices with equal values from the given array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

Suppose I have an array of size n that has some float values. I want to create a new array that has subarrays in it, where each subarray would have the indices of all elements in the original array that have equal values. So, for example, given an array givenArray=[50,20,50,20,40], the answer would be resultArray=[[0,2],[1,3],[4]].

The brute force way is to iterate on the original array, and in each iteration, iterate on the result array, compare the value to the first value in each subarray; if equal to it, add its index there. If not equal to the first value of any of the subarrays, create a new subarray and put its index there. Code for this in python would be something like:

```
resultArray=[]
for i in range(0,len(givenArray)):
    flag=0
    for j in range(0,len(resultArray)):
        if(givenArray[i]==givenArray[resultArray[j][0]]):
            resultArray[j].append(i)
            flag=1
    if(flag==0):
        resultArray.append([i])
```

This solution has a complexity of O(n^2). Can this be done at a better complexity? How? Ideas and python code would be highly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Aly

Comment: Try sorting. You will need to keep track of the original indices.

Comment: How can I track the original indices and what would be the complexity of that as well as that of the whole algorithm (assuming that sorting happens in O(n logn) for instance?

Comment: @Aly Sorting is O(n log(n)); anything else is going to be O(n), unless you make some kind of [Shlemiel the painter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070586/naming-of-an-algorithmic-antipattern) mistake. Thus the overall complexity is going to be O(n log(n)).

Comment: There are a few ways to do that. The easiest one is to sort an array of pairs (,value, original_index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `defaultdict` and `enumerate` to do this in linear time:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for i, n in enumerate(givenArray):
    result[n].append(i)
# {50: [0, 2], 20: [1, 3], 40: [4]}

result = [*result.values()]
# [[0, 2], [1, 3], [4]]
```

Note however, that your example has `int` values and not `float`. `float`s are less well-behaved as dictionary keys as they might be subject to rounding or precision errors, especially if they are results of some sort of calculations.

Comment: i don't know why i always forget about defaultdict, it's so useful

Answer (score 0):

@schwobaseggl's answer with a dict is probably the best, but for completeness, here is a solution using [**groupby**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

This solution returns the groups in increasing order of the values.

```py
import operator
import itertools

def group_indices(array):
  sorted_with_indices = sorted(enumerate(array), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
  groups = itertools.groupby(sorted_with_indices, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
  return [[i for i,v in g] for k,g in groups]

print(group_indices([50,20,50,20,40]))
# [[1, 3], [4], [0, 2]]
```

Relevant documentation:

- [builtin `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate);
- [builtin `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html);
- [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter);
- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).